# selectizeGroupUI and res_mod for two diffrent data sets but they do have common columns in r shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

I have  to display two data sets that have 5 commun columns .These 5 columns will be used for filtration in a sidebar. I managed to output every table in a Independent tabset but when i tried to filter out the data sets using those options in the sidebar i found the unique values of one dataset and not the other is there any solution:

```
selectizeGroupUI(
        id = "m",
        inline = FALSE,
        params = list(
          MEMS_flag = list(inputId = "MEMS_flag", title = "MEMS\\CMOS:"),
          Process_Family = list(inputId = "Process_Family", title = "Technology_Family:"),
          Local_Process_Id = list(inputId = "Local_Process_id", title = "Technology:"),
          Device = list(inputId = "Device", title = "Device:"),
          Customer_Name=list(inputId = "Customer_Name", title = "Customer_Name:")
        )
     ), inline = FALSE
   
    )


# The above code belongs to UI and theb below to server
  res_mod <- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "m",
    data = mergeddata1,
    vars = c("Device","MEMS_flag","Process_Family","Local_Process_id","Customer_Name"),
    inline=FALSE
    
  )

  res_mod1 <- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "m",
    data = mergeddata,
    vars = c("Device","MEMS_flag","Process_Family","Local_Process_id","Customer_Name"),
    inline=FALSE
    
  )
  output$table2 <- renderDataTable({
    input$update
    
    dato<-res_mod() 
    
    return(dato) },
    
    options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
  
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    input$update
    
    dato<-res_mod1() 
    
    return(dato) },
    
    options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
```

Comment: Please post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you want someone to help you.

Comment: @YBS i think my code is clear and it is enough to understand my problem and to help me.

Comment: Please ensure that you are using unique IDs when calling different modules.  You might be using the same ID.